# Is there a famous museum about conspiracies?

Tags: where-on-earth, museums, geek-travel

I'm a huge fan of popular conspiracy theories, like the faked moon landing, 9/11 or Nazis living in Antarctica. Is there anywhere a museum or something similar about conspiracies?

Comment: Nazis...in Antarctica? I call dibs on a rights to make a video game or a straight-to-video film, if there even is one.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee here it is explained how the Nazis create some UFOs in underground airbases in Antarctica: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazi_UFOs

Comment: Every normal man knows: Nazis are on the Moon! http://youtu.be/uX2cS8wvQHI

Comment: There was: http://www.roadsideamerica.com/story/11964

Comment: @smackfu IT STILL EXISTS I TELL YOU!! DON'T BELIEVE THOSE BIG GOVERNMENT BIG MEDIA TYPES WHO WANT TO TELL YOU IT'S CLOSED DOWN! THAT'S WHAT THEY WANT YOU TO BELIEVE! EVERYONE SHOULD LEARN THE TRUTH ABOUT THIS MUSEUM AND I CAN TELL YOU NOW THAT IT'S

Comment: wait I thought Nazi now lives in Moon or Mars...

Comment: I heard that there used to be a great museum like this, but the government shut it down!  I don't, however, have any proof of that...

Comment: Was it located in Bielefeld? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bielefeld_Conspiracy)

Comment: I added a bounty because I'm still looking for a conspiracy museum. I got some very good suggestions, but no one is really about conspiracies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It may not be the the exact controversies you are seeking, but Washington DC's [spy museum](http://www.spymuseum.org/exhibits) offers an immersive experience in the art of spycraft.

Comment: But those are not conspiracy *theories*, they're actual conspiracies.

Comment: I love the exhibit at the end **Spoiler alert** that claims to show the best spies of all time. It's empty because the best spies don't get caught or get publicity.

Answer (score 9):

It is specific to one type of conspiracy, but the [UFO Museum in Roswell, New Mexico](http://www.roswellufomuseum.com/) is interesting.

I will warn you though, the museum isn't all that fancy. Much of it looks like a high school science fair. They clearly aren't a big budget operation, but it is worth the cost of admission at least.

Answer (score 7):

Also about one particular event, the [JFK Sixth Floor Museum](http://www.jfk.org) in Dallas does a very good job covering the conspiracies about JFK's assassination.

Answer (score 4):

In Washington DC, there is the [Crime Museum](http://www.crimemuseum.org/). It is near the Spy Museum.

There is also an exhibit at the [Newseum](http://www.newseum.org/exhibits-and-theaters/temporary-exhibits/g-men-and-journalists/index.html) that might be up your alley.